# Finding the average of a column 'Category '?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large dataset, consisting of 9664 rows. I am very much new with coding, so I appreciate any help! .

This is what I have in terms of my data:

```
UserId  Date    Part_of_day    Apps         Category   Frequency      Duration_ToT
  1   2020-09-10  evening    Settings     System tool        1          3.436
  1   2020-09-11  afternoon   Calendar    Calendar           5          9.965
  1   2020-09-11  afternoon   Contacts    Phone_and_SMS      7          2.606
  2   2020-09-11  afternoon   Facebook    Social             15         50.799
  2   2020-09-11  afternoon   clock       System tool        2          5.223
  3   2020-11-18  morning    Contacts    Phone_and_SMS       3          1.726
  3   2020-11-18  morning     Google     Productivity         1          4.147
  3   2020-11-18  morning    Instagram    Social             1          0.501
  .......................................
  67  2020-11-18  morning    Truecaller   Communication     1          1.246
  67  2020-11-18  night      Instagram    Social            3          58.02
```

I want to get the average of category used per user by duration and frequency. I'am trying to represent each user by the average of category used in many time periods.

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.groupby` function

```
df.groupby(['UserId','Category']).Frequency.mean()
```

Comment: Thank you ! but how can represent each user then by the most used category (max mean frequency)

Comment: can u provide results you wanted